# How to make my bot say something different depending on the number chosen? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I'm trying to make a hownoob command, and I'm wondering how I can make it say something different depending on the range of the number?

```
@client.command()
async def hownoob(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    number = random.randint(1,100)
    member = member.mention
    yo = [f'lol yeah, {member} biggest noob here 100% :ok_hand:',
         f'noobness for {member} off the charts man!!!',
         f'{member} is a big noob, but their style is a cool noob :wink:']
    if number == 1-15:
        await ctx.send(f'noobness for {member} is {number}% which is not very noob')
    elif number == 16-49:
        await ctx.send(f'noobness for {member} is {number}% lol')
    elif number == 50-77:
        await ctx.send(f'noobness for {member} is {number}% your half noob lol XD')
    elif number == 78-89:
        await ctx.send(f'{member} is {number}%-very much noob :eyes:')
    elif number == 90-99:
        await ctx.send(f'noobness for {member} is {number}% very noob!!!!')
    elif number == 100:
        await ctx.send(f'noobness for {member} is at max!!!')
```

Thanks!

Comment: Python uses a different range format, try `if number in range(1, 16)`, `elif number in range(16, 50)`, etc. instead of what you currently have. Note: the **end** of a range is exclusive, so 15 becomes 16..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
if number in range(16):
    await ctx.send(f'noobness for {member} is {number}% which is not very noob')
elif number in range(16,50):
    await ctx.send(f'noobness for {member} is {number}% lol')
elif number in range(50,78):
    await ctx.send(f'noobness for {member} is {number}% your half noob lol XD')
elif number in range(78,90):
    await ctx.send(f'{member} is {number}%-very much noob :eyes:')
elif number in range(90,100):
    await ctx.send(f'noobness for {member} is {number}% very noob!!!!')
elif number == 100:
    await ctx.send(f'noobness for {member} is at max!!!')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought about using range, but I just didn't remember how to input it